# IF cell E2 contains "TTMBC" AND cell M2 contains a date lower than Today

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to use `AND()` function to return positive and highlight cell if two parameters in separate cells are met

If cell E2 contains "TTMBC" **AND** cell M2 contains a date lower than today.

```
=EXACT(E2,"TTMBC")
```

This will highlight for exact text match in cell E2

```
=M2<=TODAY()
```

This will highlight if M2 is lower date than today

My question is how do I combine these with `AND()` function so cell M2 will highlight only of these two parameters have been met?

Comment: You could try: `=EXACT($E2,"TTMBC")*($M2<TODAY())`

Answer (score 2):

In Excel, `AND()` is a standard worksheet function and can work as follows:

```
=AND(EXACT(E2,"TTMBC"),M2<=TODAY())
```

Good luck

Comment: Awesome I figured this was it but the autofill handle was breaking it and auto-populating dates as i dragged down the column - I got around this using Array =$M$2:$M$156

Comment: Now if I want it to find "TTMBC" in the cell (if it contains other values as well as TTMBC) I am assuming I need to use =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TTMBC",E2)) 

something like

=AND(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TTMBC",E2)),M2<=TODAY()))